# ASP.NET MVC - Get current user logged in from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, asp.net, mvc

I have an MVC web app that is sitting on a server running SharePoint Foundation and users access it via a link in the SharePoint portal. I require the website to log in automatically for the current user who is logged in to SharePoint. All I need is a way to get the user's SharePoint username so I can verify it against my database and log them in. The code below is what I have so far, but it does not seem to be working and I cannot debug as I don't have SharePoint installed.

```
        string windowsLogin = "";

        if (SPContext.Current != null)
        {
            SPSite sps = SPContext.Current.Site;
            using (SPWeb spw = sps.OpenWeb())
            {
                windowsLogin = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you say the web app is running on a server that's running SharePoint Foundation....and then you say you don't have SharePoint installed.  Which is it?

Comment: This approach will not work.  SPContext will be null because it's not running in a SharePoint context.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified, dont have it installed on my personal pc but its running on a client server with SharePoint. Thanks for your help though. I realised it won't work as my site is being loaded into a Web Part view page which doesn't sit in the SPContext